# Wildcard does not work with rename when renaming filenames in folder

Tags: rename, wildcards

I have a series of files in a folder with a string in the middle of the filenames starting with `_S` (`_S1`, `S2`, `S143` ....), which I need to get rid of/replace with just and underscore. Like this

```
file1_S1_R1 
file2_S2_R1 
file3_S95_R1
file4_S143_R1
```

which should be

```
file1_R1 
file2_R1 
file3_R1
file4_R1
```

I have tried the standard

```
rename 's/_S*_/_/g' *
```

command. However, nothing happens. Apparently, the wildcard does not work with rename on my computer. Escaping the `_` with backslash (`_` is not a reserved character anyway) or such tricks makes no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `rename` utility is the Perl `rename` utility (which takes a Perl expression, typically a substitution expression, as its 1st argument):

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file1_S1_R1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file2_S2_R1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file3_S95_R1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file4_S143_R1
```

```
$ rename 's/_S\d*_/_/g' *
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file1_R1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file2_R1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file3_R1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct  4 11:00 file4_R1
```

You got the regular expression wrong by possibly assuming that you would use a filename globbing pattern and not a Perl regular expression.  I fixed it by changing `S*` (matches zero or more `S` characters) to `S\d*` (matches an `S` followed by zero or more digits).